# "Damage screen" remains always

Tags: sniper-elite-4

My Screen is always like this, even when just standing for long time:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try using a bandage or medkit to heal your self.  I suspect you are under the impression that you heal automatically in this game.  This is not true.

Open the weapon/item wheel and select the medkit/bandage.  With it equipped, use the item like you would a grenade.  If you don't have any, you can find them by searching bodies, or searching around the map.